# rank of projection map $\pi $ of $\mathbb{P}^{n} \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology

consider the map map $\pi $ $: \mathbb{S}^{n} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n} \mathbb{R}$ obtained by resticting the projection map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n} \mathbb{R}$. What is the rank of $\pi$ at any given point?

I tried to solve it step by step by plugging in the definitions and I got something messy wich gives the right result (I'm also not sure about the correctness of this messy formula). Now the official  solution to this exercise is a bit confusing, so I would like to have suggestions on how you would solve this problem. I would appreciate any complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: To me it looks like the map is a local diffeo so the differential (in local coors) is of full rank (i.e. $n$) but perhaps that's not the def of rank in the present case? Is the official answer $n$?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh yes the official answer is n. The definition of rank is the following: for $f : M \rightarrow N$ , where $M,N$ manifolds, the rank of $f$ at $x$ is the rank of the differential of $ \sigma \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ at  $\phi(x)$ where $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are local homeomorphisms from from $M,N$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: By plugging in definitions, you should get that $m=n$ and that $\sigma \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is the identity map on open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the rank is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $e\in S^n$ and $\xi=\pi(e)$. Let $H$ be the tangent plane to $S$ at $e$. It is given by $(x-e)\cdot e=0$. Then $H$ gives local coordinates to $P^n \Bbb{R}$ in a neighborhood of $e$. (Now this depends on how you have defined local coors of projective space?). You may introduce a base in $H$ and coordinates, but that tends to obscure the idea.

$H$ also provide local coors for $S$ at $e$: 
The map $h(x) = x/|x|$ maps $H$ onto a nghb of $e$ in $S$ and the inverse is $h^{-1}(y)=y/(e\cdot y)$. So locally $S$ and $P{\Bbb R}^n$ are diffeomorphic in a nghb of $e$.